# Function returns only first element of the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

### I am trying to get every element from python list returned as a string, but it returns only the first element of the list, not continuing the loop.

**Main Code (prishot.py)**

```
import trafilatura

class prishot:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url


    def ps(self):
        downloaded = trafilatura.fetch_url(self.url)
        trafilatura.extract(downloaded)

        a = trafilatura.extract(downloaded, include_links=False, include_comments=False, include_tables=False, no_fallback=True)
        s = [sentence + '.' for sentence in a.split('.') if 'data' in sentence]
        index_list = [index for index, sentence in enumerate(s)]

        list_length = len(index_list) - 1
        num_z = 0
        while num_z < list_length:
            return s[num_z]
            num += 1
```

**Test code to run the above (test.py)**

```
from prishot import prishot

a = prishot('https://www.intuit.com/privacy/statement/')

print(a.ps())
```

After running the **test.py** it gives me only the first sentence in the list **s** in **prishot.py**:
[Screenshot of CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j95rd.png)

But if I try printing the **index_list** (which is in **prishot.py**) without the rest, you can clearly see, that there are 21 indexes there.
[Screenshot of CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvlgL.png)

So here is the output, I want it to be. As you can see here are all the sentences, which are stored in list **s** in **prishot.py**.
When running test.py it returns only the first sentence. I need to return the rest just the same as in the first picture.
[All the sentences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyNcZ.png)
[First sentence output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j95rd.png)

Comment: could you explain your desired output.

Comment: `return` means... return, so you exit the function at this point. You could build a list containing everything you want to return, then `return` it at the end.

Comment: Yes, please wait 3 minutes, I will edit the question.

Comment: @Kladeon Check the last part of my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use yield for creating a generator**

```
list_length = len(index_list) - 1
num_z = 0
while num_z < list_length:
    yield s[num_z]
    num += 1
```

**By adding this on `test.py`**

```
print(*a.ps(),sep='\n')
```

**OR,**
**You can try**
**As this outputs line by line with no change in `test.py`.**

```
list_length = len(index_list) - 1
num_z = 0
return '\n'.join(s)
```

Comment: Yes! The very last line of code worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want the whole list to be printed. if so then follow this code:

**prishot.py:**

```
import trafilatura

class prishot:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url


    def ps(self):
        downloaded = trafilatura.fetch_url(self.url)
        trafilatura.extract(downloaded)

        a = trafilatura.extract(downloaded, include_links=False, include_comments=False, include_tables=False, no_fallback=True)
        s = [sentence + '.' for sentence in a.split('.') if 'data' in sentence]

        for sentence in s:
            print(sentence)
```

**test.py:**

```
from prishot import prishot

a = prishot('https://www.intuit.com/privacy/statement/')

a.ps() # To print all sentences
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the same but in the main code? **for sentence in a.ps():** this part which is in **test.py** I want it to be in the **prishot.py**

Comment: Yes, let me edit it. But then I'll have to remove return from the method, is that fine?

Comment: That's the trick. I want return to still be present. I found a solution by the way. I used **return '\n'.join(s)** as it is said in an above answer. Anyways thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 0):

In the `while` loop you directly call `return` and that's what happens - the function directly returns a value. What you probably want to do instead, is collect the values in a list (via `my_list.append(...)`) and return *after* the `while loop` (not *in* it).

Comment: But in that case I will return a list again, won't I? I need to return not a list but every sentence in the list.

Comment: From python's point of view, you are returning a *value* and that value will always have a *type*. If you want to return multiple strings, you can do so by returning a *list of strings*.

Answer (score 0):

Now, it seems that you want to print the elements of the list **and** return the list from the function ps(). To do this, you could replace

```
    num_z = 0
    while num_z < list_length:
        return s[num_z]
        num += 1
```

with

```
    print(*s, sep='\n')
    return s
```

---

With your recent comment, it seems that you actually want each element of the list printed on a separate line. If that is the case, replace

```
    num_z = 0
    while num_z < list_length:
        return s[num_z]
        num += 1
```

with

```
    return s
```

and replace

```
print(a.ps())
```

with

```
for line in a.ps():
    print(line)
```

---

It looks like you simply want the whole list of strings concatenated together into a single string. If that is the case, replace

```
    num_z = 0
    while num_z < list_length:
        return s[num_z]
        num += 1
```

with

```
    return ''.join(s)
```

Comment: Yes, that's almost what I want, but I need to print every sentence after each other, not everything at the same time.

Comment: By "after each other", do you mean each in a separate line or do you literally mean that you want to wait for some amount of time between printing successive elements of the list?

Comment: I mean, separate line. Basically I want to return not everything at the same time, but for example create a loop which returns the first sentence, then second, third, etc.

Comment: See my latest edit

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I want. One more thing. Is there a way to combine for line in a.ps(): print(line) in the main code and not in the test file?

Comment: @Kladeon If you want a print statement in the test file, then you need to have ps() return something. If you want to print directly from the main code, then you could add `for line in s:` `...    print(line)` into the ps() method.

Comment: I want to return the same but directly from the main code and not from test file. By doing what you said, I will be just printing it.

Comment: @Kladeon You can print the strings in ps() **and** return the list of strings with ps(), if that is what you want to do.

Comment: But I will eventually return a list again? I need to return just the same thing you have already said, not from test file, but from the main code.

Comment: @Kladeon Yes, see my latest edit

Comment: is there a way to replace print(*s, sep='\n') with return? I mean, this is printing everything in the console, when I need to use **return**.

Comment: @Kladeon You said "I need to print every sentence after each other". How do you want to print it, if not in the main console? The `return` statement will not, by itself, result in any kind of print.

Comment: I found the solution, it is answered above. Here is what I used **return '\n'.join(s)**. I am sorry for not being very clear, but anyways thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Kladeon I'm glad you found your answer. For future reference, I would describe this behavior as "the function returns a string that contains each entry of the list on a separate line".

Comment: I will remember that. Thanks again :)